# I am not able to fetch items from the NgRx store and the observable remains undefined

Tags: angular, ngrx

```
import { Post } from './models/post.model';
import { AppActions, SET_POSTS } from './app.actions';

export interface State {
    posts: Post[]
}

const initialState: State = {
    posts: []
}

export function appReducer(state = initialState, action: AppActions) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SET_POSTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: action.payload
            }
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}

export const getPosts = (state: State) => state.posts;
```

So this is what I have on the reducer end, I don't think there's anything wrong with it I wrote it from the examples provided on the official documentation.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.posts$ = this.store.select(fromPost.getPosts);
    this.postService.getPosts();
  }
```

Now, the postService is working and I have been able to confirm this by logging it, but for some reason it never gets populated.

```
 .subscribe((posts: Post[]) => {
    this.store.dispatch(new AppAction.SetPosts(posts));
 }
```

When I log posts, I get the expected output, so I am wondering if it's the dispatch that's being improperly called or handled.

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Posts } from './models/post.model';

export const SET_POSTS = 'Set Posts';

export class SetPosts implements Action {
    readonly type = SET_POSTS;
  
    constructor(public payload: Post[]) {}
}

export type AppActions = SetPosts;
```

This is the post actions, so I don't see anything wrong with it or is there?

Update:

```
   this.posts$ = this.store.select(fromPost.selectPosts);
   this.postService.getPosts();
   console.log(this.posts$);
   this.posts$.subscribe( value => console.log(value));
   //Object { _isScalar: false, actionsObserver: {…}, reducerManager: {…}, source: {…}, operator: {…} }

   //undefined
```

I also made some changes in the reducer:

```
const getPosts = (state: State) => state.posts;

export const selectState = (state: State) => state;
export const selectPosts = createSelector(
  selectState,
  getPosts
);
```

I am still getting nothing when I do this in my html file:

```
<div *ngIf="(posts$ | async) as posts">
  <div *ngFor="let post of posts">
    {{ post.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: make it a bit easier for you self to identify the problem. use the subscribe object instead, `observable.subscribe({ next: (posts: post[]=> { ... }, error: err=> {console.error(err)}, complete: ()=> {console.log('comleted')});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, you have write a selector to bind the post to the UI.

Create Selector.ts file

```
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromPost from 'post.reducer'

export const selectState = (state: State) => state;
export const selectPost = createSelector(
  selectState,
  fromPost.getPosts
);
```

In your component

```
constructor() {
  this.store.dispatch(new LoadPost())
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.posts$ = this.store.select(selectPost);
  }
```

Create an effect that calls `postService`, async services are side effects to the store and should be handled through Effects.
[Documentation for Setting up effects](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects)

create posts action.ts

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store'

export enum PostActionTypes {
  LoadPost = '[Post] Load Post',
  SetPosts = '[Post] Load Post Success',
  LoadPostFailure = '[Post] Load Post Failure',
}

export class LoadPost implements Action {
  readonly type = PostActionTypes.LoadPost
}

export class SetPosts implements Action {
  readonly type = PostActionTypes.SetPosts
  constructor(public payload: Post[]) {}
}

export class LoadPostFailure implements Action {
  readonly type = PostActionTypes.LoadPostFailure
  constructor(public payload: any) {}
}

export type PostActions = 
| LoadPost
| SetPosts
| LoadPostFailure
```

create Post effect.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Actions, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects'
import { of } from 'rxjs'
import { catchError, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Injectable()
export class PostEffects {
  constructor(private postService: PostService, private actions$: Actions) {}

  @Effect()
  loadPosts$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(PostActions.LoadPost),
    switchMap(() => {
      return this.postService.getPosts().pipe(
        map(posts => new SetPosts(posts)),
        catchError(error => of(new LoadPostFailure(error)))
      )
    })
  )
}
```

NOTE: Effects are Injectable classes, make sure you add them to

```
NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    ...    
    EffectsModule.forRoot([ ... effects ]), // Effect classes as CSV
    ...
  ]
})
```

Comment: getPost is the pure function implemented in the reducer (your code is doing it). getPost will get the post array and then will be used in the selector. You bind selectors to the UI.

Comment: Hmm, I implemented the selectors, but I still get undefined. Look at update

Comment: I did my own implementation of selectors later after I originally posted the question, but even your changes didn't make any difference for some reason, I am thinking the posts doesn't get dispatched correctly. Is there anything wrong with SetPosts? And how would you debug this?

Comment: it could be related to the fact the service is not implemented with Effects, create an effect that calls  getPosts() service method and dispatches the SetPost  Actions.

Comment: Are effects necessary? I relied on this project to make my own application: https://github.com/garimagupta2210/fitness-tracker-Angular9/blob/master/src/app/training/new-training/new-training.component.ts

Comment: Effects are parts of NGRX echo system, they are meant to handle the async side effects like fetching data from the server. I updated the answer to include the effect for the POST.
You have to update the component and in the constructor dispatch LoadPost action and remove service call from onNgInit